# find the singular value and eigenvalue of A?

Tags: linear-algebra

find the  singular value of the $ n \times  n $ real symmetrics matrices .

$$A=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & 1 &  ... & 1\\
  1 & -1 & ... & 0 \\
  .& .& . &  .\\
  .& . & . & .\\
  . & .&  & . \\1 & 0 & ... & -1
\end{matrix}\right)$$

What are the  eigenvalue  of  the   matrix  $A $  ?
this  is orginal question photo .

[image]

My attempts:  Here  A is symmetrics, as  i know  that if  A  is a real symmetrics matrics ,then the singular value are  absolute value of the eigenvalue of A..

here  matrix  is $n \times  n $,  so  im very  confuse  how to find the  eigenvalue..

Any hints/solution will be aprreciated

Thanks  in advance

Comment: I'm not clear as to what the pattern is here. Is it $1$s in the first row and column, $-1$ elsewhere on the diagonal, and $0$s elsewhere off the diagonal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the pattern suggested by Theo Bendit, let $x$ be a vector and calculating $Ax$ gives:
$$
Ax=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  1 & 1 &  ... & 1\\
  1 & -1 & ... & 0 \\
  .& .& . &  .\\
  .& . & . & .\\
  . & .&  & . \\1 & 0 & ... & -1
\end{matrix}\right)\left(\begin{matrix} 
  x_1\\
  x_2 \\
  .\\
  .\\
  .\\
  x_n
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
This gives
$$
Ax=\left(\begin{matrix} 
  x_1+x_2+..+x_n\\
  x_1-x_2 \\
  x_1-x_3\\
  .\\
  .\\
  x_1-x_n
\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Now to find eigenvalues, consider $Ax-\lambda x$
$$
Ax-\lambda x = \left(\begin{matrix} 
  x_1+x_2+..+x_n - \lambda x_1\\
  x_1-(\lambda+1)x_2 \\
  x_1-(\lambda+1)x_3\\
  .\\
  .\\
  x_1-(\lambda+1)x_n
\end{matrix}\right)\qquad(1)
$$
Now if we make $\lambda = -1$ and $x_1 = 0$, we get first element of $Ax-\lambda x$ as $x_2+x_3+...+x_n$ and remaining all elements as zeros. To make first element zero, we can do it in n-1 ways varying $x_2, x_3,..$etc in such a way that corresponding $x$ eigenvectors are independent and $\sum_{i=2}^n x_i = 0$.

With this we get $n-1$ eigenvalues as $-1$.

To find other eigenvalue, equate (1) to zero. We get from 1st element:
$$
x_1+x_2+...+x_n - \lambda x_1 = 0
$$
$$
x_2+x_3+...+x_n = (\lambda - 1) x_1 \qquad(2)
$$
Adding all the remaining $n-1$ equations:
$$
(n-1)x_1 = (\lambda+1)(x_2+x_3+...+x_n)
$$
From (2)
$$
(n-1)x_1 = (\lambda+1)(\lambda - 1) x_1
$$
since we have already considered $x_1 = 0$ case, we get
$$
\lambda ^2 = n
$$
or $\lambda = \sqrt n$. Note that $\lambda$ cannot be equal to $- \sqrt n$ as it will mean $n<1$

So we have $n$ eigenvales as $\sqrt n, -1, -1, ... $(n-1)times

Comment: thanks  a lots @artha

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Assuming the pattern is as Theo Bendit suggested, you can take $n-2$ eigenvectors in the form $u_2 - u_j$ (where $u_j$ is the vector with $1$ in position $j$ and $0$ elsewhere), while the other two eigenvectors are of the form
$$ \pmatrix{a\cr  1\cr .\cr .\cr .\cr 1\cr}$$

Comment: ..how you came to know about the elements of eigenvector?Kindly give more hints.